# Increase Font Image Mouse Over

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, javascript

This may not be possible without jQuery ToolTip, but I want to try.

Scenerio:  I would like to increase the font size in the description located in the mouse hover whether it's a image or a list item.

To Solve: add the following code and increase the font according to desired size.

```
    .hoverinfo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is not right, but I wanted to try.  I wanted to apply the code per page not by master page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Place the code in a new CSS file, upload it to your style library. Then in Site Settings, click on Master Page and apply this CSS file as an alternate CSS file and apply it to all subsites as well.

This would be for a single site collection, repeat as necessary, or script up something to walk through your farm and apply it to all sites.